# Specify color for each listview row

Tags: java, android, listview, background-color

I fill my ListView with this code:

```
    final ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvKinder);
    ArrayList<Kind> kisi = datenfuerlistview();
    KinderlistAdapter kiadapter = new KinderlistAdapter(this, kisi);
    lv.setAdapter(kiadapter);
    final DBHelper db = new DBHelper(this);
```

Now I want to analyse one entry of every `Kind` object I add to my `ListView`. If it has a certain value, I want to change the backgroundcolor for this `ListView` entry.

Here´s my adapter:

```
@Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder;

        if(convertView == null){
            convertView = inflator.inflate(R.layout.list_black_text, parent, false);
            holder = new ViewHolder((TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.nullline), (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.firstLine), (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imgv));

            convertView.setTag(holder);
        }
        else{
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        Kind ki = (Kind) getItem(position);
        holder.getName().setText(ki.getName());
        holder.getDatum().setText(ki.getDatum());

        Uri uri = Uri.parse(ki.getGeschlecht());

        String path = ki.getKinderbild();

        System.out.println("HSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSS" + path);
        //holder.getGeschlecht().setImageBitmap(bitmap);

        ContentResolver cr = context.getContentResolver();
        Bitmap tmp = null;
        try {
            tmp = getThumbnail(cr, path);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("NAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA") ;
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        holder.getGeschlecht().setImageBitmap(tmp);

        return convertView;
```

How to set the color?

Comment: you can simply check it using if condition with `ki.getName()` and change the color accordingly..

Comment: But how can I access the color of the listview in a 'extends BaseAdapter' class

Comment: why do u want to set the color of the listview?..u can just do what Damien R had suggested it the if conditions..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you tried this ? (before returning convertView) :

```
convertView.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);//or another color
```

Comment: Sorry, maybe I was not exact enough. 
I have to check if the value is "m" or "w", and set a different color for each